# how to Pass aws credential keys to KinesisProducerConfiguration to create kinesis producer in java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-java-sdk-2.x

this is code i found on aws documentation.

```
KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();
config.setRegion("us-west-1");
config.setMaxConnections(1);
config.setCredentialsProvider(new AWSCredentialsProviderChain());
config.setCredentialsProvider(new AWSCredentialsProviderChain());

KinesisProducer KProducer = new KinesisProducer(config);
```

can any help help to how to provide credentials to this config object

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aws-kinesis)

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
KinesisProducerConfiguration producerConfig = new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
  .setCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
  .setVerifyCertificate(false)
  .setRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.getName());

this.kinesisProducer = new KinesisProducer(producerConfig);
```